# Why don't we evaluate algorithms by their median-case complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

We have three ways to evaluate an algorithm:
Worst case
Best case
And avg case

The first tells us to look at the worst possible input for the algorithm, and evaluate it's performance.

The second tells us to look at the best input for our algorithm.

The last tells us to look at the avg case of input to the algorithm and so it may be a more accurate measure of an algorithm's performance.

Why aren't we considering an algorithm by it's median case, it's surly be a more accurate then avg-case or at least be complementary factor to it.
Because we look at an input that half of the possible input are below it and above it.

median gives the weight needed to the input that avg may not give.

Comment: Purely Computer Science related questions are better asked at [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). StackOverflow is about *programming*, not why we do complexity analysis in a certain way. Anyway, IMHO 1) how could you compute that? 2) The average case is actually parametrized by the distribution of the inputs. If you know that the inputs are mostly uniformly distributed than average=median. Most of the time we really don't have any reasonable distribution to use other than the uniform one.

Comment: Didn't know about cs.stackexchange.com, will look at it, thanks.

I get what you are saying, and you are right about average=median.
And usually we really don't know to much about the input. 
But if we do know something, why not use it, you know?

Answer (score 2):

Median doesn't really have very useful statistical properties.

One thing useful about average is that it becomes asymptotically more unlikely that you will get bad input.

Suppose that average run-time of your algorithm is `f(n)` in 60% cases and `g(n)` in 40% cases, where `g(n) >> f(n)`. Then your median is `Θ(f(n))`, but your solution would often not fit in a time-slot for `f(n)` algorithm. However, even if probability for `g(n)` is a very small constant, average will still be `Θ(g(n))` alerting you that the algorithm might run for a long time.

Other useful property of expected value is summing. If you have a number of tasks executed sequentially then average total run-time will be equal to a total of average run-times. This makes average easier to both derive and use. There is no similar property for medians.